# How to switch between items of carousel

Tags: wordpress, custom-controls, owl-carousel

Is there any way I can switch between items of carousel using a button or hyperlink on the same page. I am working on wordpress and was unable to find any particular case on this problem. If you can please provide a solution or share a link which will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should add button controls in your html.

```
                <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel_slider_id" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel_slider_id" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
```

Make sure to update 'carousel_slider_id' with your carousal slider id.